# Python/Raspberry Pi: BCM pin permanently giving high signal

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm writing a script that will allow you to push 3 buttons and control another person's LED's over MQTT.
The way I check if a button is pressed is through an interrupt/add_event_detect:

```
io.add_event_detect(btn1,io.FALLING,callback=lambda *a: snd_msg(1),bouncetime=500)
io.add_event_detect(btn2,io.FALLING,callback=lambda *a: snd_msg(2),bouncetime=500)
io.add_event_detect(btnMaster,io.FALLING,callback=lambda *a: snd_msg(3),bouncetime=500)
```

The two first ones work fine, but the third one gets called permanently without any button being pressed.
This is the pins they're using currently:

```
btn1 = 2 #red
btn2 = 3 #yellow
btnMaster = 18 #green
io.setmode(io.BCM)
io.setup(btn1, io.IN)
io.setup(btn2, io.IN)
io.setup(btnMaster, io.IN)
```

I've also tried pin 4 for btnMaster but I get the same result. I'm guessing this has to do with the pullup in pins 2 and 3 in BCM mode, but I don't really know how to fix this.

This is the output when I run the script: 
[output picture](http://prntscr.com/f7czsb)

I can provide more code if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, so I figured I'd post it here as well.
It was indeed the pins, since pin 2 & 3 in BCM mode have a builtin pullup resistor of 1.8 kOhms.
I basically just attached the master button that was giving me issues with a pullup resistor as well through this [tutorial](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/robot/buttons_and_switches/).